# How much liquid hydrogen is required to veer a manned probe off course into an escape trajectory in deep space?

Tags: space, space-travel, spaceships

> This is totally not based off the Lost Cosmonauts Theory, what are you talking about??

I am working on this horror-scifi story <s>based on the lost cosmonauts theory, where the Judica-Cordiglia brothers detected an SOS from a manned probe veering off into space before Yuri Gagarin</s> ahem... I didn't say that.

Basically, a team of astronauts are sent by an private space research agency *(Definitely not SpaceX, lmao)* in a manned capsule to explore the outer solar system, especially between the orbits of Saturn and Uranus, for well... ^plot reasons^

The astronauts then spot a weird metallic spiky "asteroid" floating around in space. They come up close, and actually discover that it is not a "asteroid", but a really old probe. After docking with the probe, they discover to their horror, that there are several paper pages lying on the floor of the probe, and more unsettling, the preserved corpse of a dead <s>cosmo</s> astronaut.

The astronauts read the paper pages. It seems to be a sort of rant written down by the (dead) astronaut, about how he got lost in space.

Apparently, he was the first man to be launched into space, as the result of a space race between two global powers, whom we shall call A and B. The astronaut was launched by A, into orbit, to study cosmic radiation and stuff. However, as soon as he was scheduled to land on Earth, his retrorockets misfired in the wrong direction. Unfortunately, the controls were jammed due to some reason, so the astronaut had to watch in sheer terror, as he watched Earth getting smaller and smaller through the window. He knew his probe was on an escape trajectory and veering into deep space. He sent an SOS, in a last attempt, and eventually commited s****de by opening the hatchlock and suffocating in the vacuum.

Now of course, I may be experienced at Astronomy and stuff, but absolutely suck at aerospace engineering. (I don't think if retrorockets even have buttons to control them). So here are some dumb attempts at drawing a parallel between this situation and known rockets.

The rocket that fired A's astronaut into space can be comparable to the Saturn V. And the rocket engines were Bell nozzles, similar to what the Space Shuttle used.

As far as I have heard, retrorockets don't even use liquid fuels, let alone LH2 (Wasn't it something like, I dunno, a nitro- compound or smth?). But again, this is interesting for the plot, because maybe they were trying to experiment with different fuels?

But anyways, considering the real story:

The amount of fuel to get on an escape trajectory is astounding. It takes like 3 million pounds of fuel for launching something like the Space shuttle to LEO, forget escape trajectory. And the probe, was well, found drifting between the orbits of Saturn and Uranus, about a billion miles away, last time I checked.

Considering that the astronaut in the story was sent into a escape trajectory from LEO to about 1 billion miles away, I am sure it would have taken a **B*ttload** of liquid hydrogen for the retrorockets to actually misfire that bad. This brings me to my question:

**How much liquid hydrogen is required as fuel to veer a manned probe off course into an escape trajectory?**

Some additional info:

- The probe, in question was found orbiting between the orbits of Uranus and Saturn, which suggests that it may have slowed down due to the gravitational force of the two planets, and settled into a orbit.
- After doing some research, I found out that the velocity of the rocket must not have been greater than [13.6 km/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity#Scenarios:%7E:text=At%20Saturn-,The%20Sun%27s%20gravity,-13.6) or [9.6 km/s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity#Scenarios:%7E:text=At%20Uranus-,The%20Sun%27s%20gravity,-9.6).
- The fuel being used by the retro-rockets is liquid hydrogen, with liquid oxygen being used as oxidizer.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is something wrong with my question, please point it out.

Comment: Liquid hydrogen is a complete non-starter for retrothrusters due to its propensity to boil off. For a launch to orbit, where you can keep pumping in propellant up until the last minutes before launch, this isn't so bad, but retrorocket propellant needs to stay in the tank until fired. You'd need to carry (complex, *very* heavy) cryogenic equipment to keep it in its liquid state all the way to orbit. An aside: the nitrogen compound you're thinking of is probably [hydrazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazine#Rocket_fuel), possibly UDMH + nitric acid.

Comment: I say this is better asked on Astronomy.SE, yet I've heard that there's more people in here that could answer such questions than there.  Yet you're really into very high delta-V ranges with this, perhaps an easy answer won't do.

Comment: Why are you censoring "suicide"? I'm not sure how worldbuilding.se could be mistaken for tiktok.

Comment: @StarfishPrime If you hang around Spam-Central ([charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)) long enough, you'll see all sorts. Automatic filters would seem necessary to you, I'm sure. Never seen invitations or advice on the "S" word, but it probably seemed like a good idea at the time the word was added to the trigger list.

Comment: @Escapeddentalpatient. its the presumption that tiktok-style linguistic constraints apply to the rest of the interwebs that irritates me. Like, this is a site that regularly covers things like arson, murder, genocide and slavery (though not torture that much these days) and yet the assumption is that you can't say "butt", (though sticking an asterisk in there makes it a-ok). I'm pretty certain we can say butt here. Butt butt butt. Its OK.

Comment: Buuuutt. The powers applied blanket rules for the network. WB would seem to require exemption (as with psychology, medical sciences and maybe the literary/fiction sites and possibly arguably history.  Presumably the language ones too as etymology is on-topic AFAIK). One size fits all I guess, usual story. @StarfishPrime Irritating, yep.

Answer (score 6):

### About 70.8 metric tons

To plot courses around the solar system, I find this chart handy:

[image: delta-v map]

<sub>[Source: Slightly upgraded delta v map of the solar system](https://www.reddit.com/r/RealSolarSystem/comments/fq4ky5/slightly_upgraded_delta_v_map_of_the_solar_system/)</sub>

To get from one orbit to another, simply travel along the tree and add the delta-v at each step. An Earth-Uranus transfer looks to be about 8.4 km/s, assuming a start from LEO already at 9 km/s. If the spacecraft is to stay near Uranus, then a Uranus capture is an additional 510 m/s, bringing the total delta-v, $d_{v}$, to 8.9 km/s.

The [Vostok 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostok_1) capsule had a launch mass of around 5000 kg, I'll assume that's our capsule mass. As a guestimate, I'll assume the fuel tank mass is 6000 kg. Because the tanks carry our fuel, we have to haul them the whole way to our destination, and so they factor into our final "dry" mass, or the mass of the spacecraft after all fuel is spent, $m_{dry}=m_{capsule}+m_{tanks}$, which totals to 11000 kg. I'll also assume our hydrolox engine has a specific impulse, $I_{sp}$, of 450 s, which is pretty good. With these figures we can calculate the propellent mass, $m_{prop}$:

$$v_{e}=9.98\cdot I_{sp} \text{ m/s}$$
$$R=\exp\left(\frac{d_{v}}{v_{e}}\right)$$
$$m_{wet}=R\cdot m_{dry} \text{ kg}$$
$$m_{prop}=m_{wet}-m_{dry} \text{ kg}$$

Propellant mass for Uranus insertion runs to 70.8 metric tons. To find the hydrogen and oxygen fuel masses independently, we rely on a fuel mass ratio. The stoichiometric ratio of LOX to LH is 8:1, but maximum specific impulse is at ~4.3:1 (though most engines run with less hydrogen, at ratios of 5-6:1).
$$m_{LOX}=m_{prop}\left(\frac{4.3}{4.3+1}\right)$$
$$m_{LH}=m_{prop}\left(\frac{1}{4.3+1}\right)$$

Of our 70.8 metric tons of fuel, 57.4 are LOX and 13.4 are LH.

You'll want to cycle back to see whether your tank mass guestimate was a good one by looking at the tank mass fraction:
$$\frac{m_{prop}}{m_{tanks}}$$

For LOX/LH, an optimistic tank mass ratio is probably ~10:1, and ours is in that ballpark.

Comment: While this will get you out of an Earth-centric orbit into a Sun-centric orbit, you'll still be at around Earth's orbital distance from the Sun. You'd need to put in an extra ~5 km/s at least to get out between Saturn and Uranus's orbital distances.

Comment: @Cadence Ah, missed that part. Let me edit that into my answer...

Comment: Thanks for the expansion, it looks like really good work. I was expecting it to be higher of course but not *that* much higher! I guess that's the rocket equation for you.

Comment: @Cadence Thanks! Realistically though, a rocket with *that much* delta-v should be staged. I should probably revisit this answer again later to look at that.

Comment: I think you've more than answered the background question of "could a capsule spiral off into space like this", but I'd be keen to see the effect of staging too.

Comment: So... just a bit more than the retros would likely be carrying, then.

Comment: This capsule looks like it was designed to actually land to Earth by its own rockets, and not drop a pod and disintegrate. An SSFO, if you like. Why else they would have this much fuel on board? But I'd dare that LOX+LH would boil away at reentry, leaving the capsule with not enough fuel to completely decelerate, making the project dead on arrival. Interesting, hmm.

Comment: @Vesper Yeah, boil off would kill this rocket, unless maybe it was destined to shoot off to Uranus right away instead of lingering in LEO. Still, there'd be no fuel left for an insertion burn at Uranus. I don't believe a hydrolox engine has ever been used out past geostationary, either.

Comment: From BMF's reply it appears an unlikly amount of fuel would be required, butyou might be able to reduce that a bit if you allowed for some gravitational boosting as has been used to get probes to jupiter/saturn...pluto etc. It would require a very unlikely initial trajectory, but if the retro-rocket errror provided just enough energy to get to Mars or Venus, then it may be possible to ger past Saturn via a series of slingshots around the moon, mars, earth, venus, earth again, etc... Assuming time is not an issue, you may just need minimum fuel to reach Mars or Venus orbit.

Comment: @Penguino Your reply reminded me that the orbit might not work at all. Spacecraft are usually launched in the direction of Earth's rotation, which is canted at an angle off from the ecliptic plane. You wouldn't reach anywhere near Uranus unless it was a deliberate act.

Comment: Which is true regardless. A random thruster burn will send you basically anywhere except a planet. But even more delta-v would be required for the plane change, or a gravity assist.

Comment: If time was not (much of) an objection, could the probe have followed the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_Transport_Network route?